# Could someone tell me how I could handle this code object oriented wise.

Tags: php

Although I know the basics of OOP, I just dont know how to make this normal php code act like OOP. What I wrote down is a rock paper scissor kinda game. Does someone please want to sacrifice some time to help me, I really want to get better at it. I would be grateful.

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {

        $array = array('water', 'wood' 'fire');
        $enemy_guess = array_rand(1,3);
        $player_guess = $_POST['picked_skill'];

            switch ($player_guess){

            case 'water':

                if($enemy_guess == 'fire'){
                        echo "you won";
                    }
                }else
                    {
                        echo "you lost";
                    }
            break;

            case 'wood':

                if($enemy_guess == 'water'){
                        echo "you won";
                }
                }else
                    {
                        echo "you lost";
                    }
            break;

            case 'fire':

                if($enemy_guess == 'wood'){
                        echo "you won";
                }
                }else
                    {
                        echo "you lost";
                    }
            break;
        }

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: So... you want someone to rewrite that in an OOP style?

Comment: It's a very simple code, why do you consider switching it to OOP?

Comment: I bet you never win this game because of the bug. Also, there can be no tie.

Comment: Not rewrite it, but explain how it would be done in OOP. and well

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example, take into account that you do not consider the draw scenario, so I didn't either.
If you have questions, go ahead and make them :)

```
class Game {

   private $player_guess;
   private $enemy_guess;
   private $rules = array( //basically, water beats fire, fire beats wood and wood beats water, anything else is a lose scenario.
           array("water" => "fire"),
           array("fire" => "wood"),
           array("wood" => "water"));

   private $options = array("water", "wood", "fire");


   public function compGuess() {    
        $this->enemy_guess = array_rand($this->options);
   }
   public function playerGuess($guess) {
        $this->player_guess = $guess;
   }

   public function result() {
        if($this->rules[$this->enemy_guess] == $this->player_guess) {
          echo "You loose";
        } else {
           echo "You WIN!";       
        }

   }
}

//Usage:
$game = new Game();
$game->compGuess();
$game->playerGuess($_POST['picked_skill']);
$game->result();
```

Comment: I was in the middle of answering with an example that demonstrated several OO concepts in PHP, but this is great so I stopped. :) +1

Comment: Thanks, I realize it's not SUPER OOP,but the example is too simple and the question asked shows that the OP should get into OOP one step at the time...

Comment: Well, putting everything inside ONE class is not really OOP, is it?

Comment: There are millions of possible valid answers, did I use OOP? yes, can it get more complex and use other aspects of OOP that I didn't touch? yes. The OP wanted a way to do this with OOP, not the best OOP design for it.

Answer (score 0):

A rough strategy would be to model the two players guesses as a class. Putting input validation inside to ensure no invalid guesses are taken.

Next would be a comparison function to see who wins. You compare one guess with another like this:

```
$result = $guess->compare($otherGuess);
```

I'd let you try this at this point... :)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do OOP, it's up to you.  Here's what I'd do.

```
class Skill
{
    static $skills = array("Wood", "Water", "Fire");
    $skill;

    __construct($skill)
    {
        if is_int($skill)
        {
            $this->skill = $skill;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->skill = array_search($skill, self::$skills);
        }
    }

    function Beats($other)
    {
        $beat_other = $other->skill - 1;
        if($beat_other < 0)
        {
            $beat_other = count(self::$skills) - 1;
        }
        if($beat_other == $this->skill)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

$Enemy_Skill = new Skill(rand(0,2));
$My_Skill = new Skill($_POST['picked_skill']);

if($My_Skill->Beats($Enemy_Skill))
{
    echo "You Win";
}
elseif($Enemy_Skill->Beats($My_Skill))
{
    echo "You Lose";
}
else
{
    echo "Draw";
}
```